# Probability density function of max(X,Y) - X

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence

Assume we have random variable $W =\max(X,Y) - X$, I would like to find the pdf of $W$. 
Here, X, Y are independent continuous random variables.
Does the following work?
$$
F_W(w)=\mathbb{P}[W≤w]=\mathbb{P}[\max(X,Y)-X≤w]=\mathbb{P}[0≤w]\mathbb{P}[Y-X≤w]=F_X(w)F_Y(w+x)
$$ 
And then what should I do?

Comment: Hi, I have edited your post to use MathJAX formatting. Please check to be sure that the new text is what you mean.

Comment: yes, its fine . thank you very much

Comment: It is perfectly fine to attack the problem from the CDF but the second step is a mysterious one. When dealing with these kinds of piece-wise function, you really look into case by case to see what things happen. When $Y \leq X$ and provided that this happen with non-zero probability, $W = 0$ and thus $W$ is a mixture of a discrete and continuous random variable. It has a point mass at $0$ with probability $\Pr\{Y \leq X\}$. You can continue to try to work on the continuous part when $Y > X$. You may start with the law of total probability at step 2.